# sharp/flat shading edges on low poly mesh

Tags: modeling

I would like to be able to apply a kind of "flat shading" only for some selected edges on an object, as we can see in the screenshot (sketchfab matcap mod). Since I need to export my object, the effect would have to be compatible with an FBX, OBJ or glTF format.

Thank you

[image: flat shading edges]

Comment: Extra edge loops are you best option for exporting to obj

Comment: Do you mean support loops? If yes, it's not an option for what I want to do. As you can see on picture, there is no support loops, and the sharping works with Sketchfab.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way (and I guess this is the only one if we don't want to split edges)

- activate auto-smooth and set it to 180
- mark as sharp the edges you want sharp

It works at least for glTF export (I didn't try other formats)